# How to access original data after applying d3.stratify()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a large CSV structured like this:

```
id,value
Animal,
Animal.Cat,
Animal.Cat.Female,
Animal.Cat.Female.Domestic,
Animal.Cat.Female.Domestic.Kittn,
Animal.Cat.Female.Domestic.Kittn.Brown,
Animal.Cat.Female.Domestic.Kittn.Brown.Pearl,"Pearl.Cat.Domestic.Brown.Female.Kittn.43529.K19-032349.Ca03.A387384.05/25/2019.05/29/2019.4.Stray.Over_The_Counter.Transfer.Hssc.Treatable/Rehab.Treatable/Rehab.County.County.95407.95407(38.403734,_-122.736775).1"
Animal.Cat.Male,
Animal.Cat.Male.Domestic,
Animal.Cat.Male.Domestic.Small,
Animal.Cat.Male.Domestic.Small.Brown,
Animal.Cat.Male.Domestic.Small.Brown.Elliott,"Elliott.Cat.Domestic.Brown.Male.Small.05/31/2005.K19-032383.Vet.A387892.05/31/2019.05/31/2019.0.Stray.Field.Euthanize..Unknown.Dead.Santa_Rosa.Santa_Rosa.95404.95404(38.458384,_-122.675588).1"
```

I am using the d3-hierarchy module to create a tree diagram. After constructing a hierarchy by using `d3.stratify` I try to access the original values `id` and `value` from the CSV:

```
nodes.append("text")
   .text(function(d) { 
      var string = d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
      console.log(d.id + " " + d.value);
      return string.replace(/_/g, " "); 
      })
```

Using `d.id` successfully gets the `id` value but logging `d.value` yields `undefined`.

Here is an executable [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-wildflower-heepe?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: In most of the records in your data, `value` isn't present - is that your problem? And `value` looks like a kind of CSV as well

Comment: @Mikkel That's not my problem. It doesn't have to be defined for most records, and value should just be a value. The reason it contains so many dots is because I was going to just split it up after processing the CSV.

Comment: This question isn't really related to the specifics of d3-hierarchy, since that wouldn't modify the value of "d", that would be the code that loads the CSV (probably d3-dsv or d3-fetch). Can you post the code that you're using to load the data/CSV using codesandbox or codepen? As @Mikkel said, from the sample you posted, it looks like we'd expect `value` to be undefined for all but 2 of the rows in the sample you've posted.

Comment: @CameronYick Empty columns will not result in the properties being `undefined`; empty values are resolved to empty strings, i.e. `""`: https://jsfiddle.net/1tgokrjs/ This question definitely needs more information and code reproducibly demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @altocumulus I have added a link to the code. The full visualisation is different but the code in the sandbox demonstrates my issue. This is based on the radial tidy tree from the GitHub d3 gallery. I am new to both d3 and JavaScript so sorry if this is a super basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a hierarchy using the stratify operator [`d3.stratify`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#stratify) the original data is stored in the nodes' [`.data`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/src/hierarchy/index.js#L59) property. You need to access that property to obtain your values. The `id` property you witnessed on the nodes is a red herring as it is the internal ID [created](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/src/stratify.js#L34-L35) by D3 by applying the [`stratify.id()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#stratify_id) accessor. Because you did not specify an accessor on your own the default kicks in which uses an already existing `.id` property. For this reason the internal ID equals your original ID; for other cases involving a different accessor this could be any artificially constructed ID, though.

To access your original values you should always resort to the `.data` property of the nodes instead. For your code this would be:

```
nodes.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { 
    const data = d.data;   // The .data property contains your original values
    console.log(data.id + " " + data.value);
    // ...
  });
```